# What is the Amazon Lex's equivalent of IBM Conversation Service's entity's synonyms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

Specifically say if we're designing OrderFood intent, IBM has an option to create an entity of type @sandwich and to which we can assign possible synonyms like (cheese steak, french dip, pastrami and what not).

Conversation service would return this entity @sandwich when the synonym is entered. Like when an user enters "french dip", it'll return @sandwich and not "french dip"

In Amazon, we've slot types but it returns "french dip" and not @sandwich. 
See
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#defining-entities for reference

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking to get the name of a slot rather than the value?

Comment: Not exactly. If the utterance is "Order me a french dip", I'm looking for {foodType:sandwich} instead of {foodType:french dip}. "French dip" is one of the synonym of sandwich and sandwich is the value of slot "foodType"

Comment: I don't think it can do this. The user has asked for a `French Dip` so that is what Lex will return. You'd have to use a validation function to convert the value, which would be manually coded by you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment :

> Not exactly. If the utterance is "Order me a french dip", I'm looking
>   for {foodType:sandwich} instead of {foodType:french dip}. "French dip"
>   is one of the synonym of sandwich and sandwich is the value of slot
>   "foodType"

Possible solution is:

- Create a slot foodType
- Tick on Restrict to Slot values and Synonyms
- Give value as sandwich
- Add as many synonyms as you like, eg frenchdip, french dip, sand
  wich, sauce
- Add the slot to your bot
- Build your bot

This will give value as sandwich.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not working on this project anymore so I couldn't validate this. But this response sounds something like what I looking for. Hence accepting your answer.